Confusion about Polya's urn
I encountered Polya's Urn in two of my lecturers. One is from elementary probability, the other is from Advanced probability after formally defining conditional expectation and martingale.
Suppose we have a Urn and at time $0$, we have one white ball and one blue ball in it. At each discrete time (trial) $n$, the player takes out a ball uniformly from the urn, and returns the ball along with a new ball of the same color to the urn. Let $W_n$ be the number of white balls after trial $n$.
Intuitively, we have $P(W_1=W_0| W_0) =1/2$, $P(W_1=W_0+1| W_0) =1/2$. (This is also what I learned in elementary probability).
However, we formalize $P(W_1=W_0| W_0) : = E(1_{\{W1=W0\}}|\sigma(W_0)) = E(1_{\{W1=W0\}})= P(W_0=W_1) =1/2$ since $\sigma(W_0)$ is trivial.
I am confused about doing the same for bigger $n$. It is intuitively that $P(W_{n+1}=W_n| W_0, W_1, \cdots, W_n)= \frac{n+2-W_n}{n+2}$, which is hard to make it compatible to statements above.
$P(W_{n+1}=W_n| W_0, W_1, \cdots, W_n)=E(1_{\{W_{n+1}=W_{n}\}}|\sigma(W_0, W_1, \cdots, W_n)) =?$
Suppose $X \in L_1$ or non-negative,
We say $W$ is a version of $E(X|Y)$ iff

It is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable
$E(X1_{A})= E(W1_A), \forall A \in \sigma(Y)$

